# placing a rectangle with text on top of svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to place a rectangle on which text is printed on top of an svg.

when running this code, I get the rectangle, but it does not appear on top of the image, and there is no text on top of the rectangle.

I have partially solved the issue. still need to move the rectangle, and would appreciate help doing so.

Presently, it is going over the image, but not in the correct place. here is the new code:

```
div class = "video-container">
          <img class = "video" src="./images/play-video.svg" alt="play-video" />
          <svg width="190" height="63">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="63" fill="blue"/>
              <text x="50%" y="50%"  fill="white" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Play Video</text>
          </svg>
      </div>
```

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.video-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

HTML & SVG

Group them inside `<g></g>`

```
<div class = "video-container">
  <svg>
      <g>
        <rect class = "rect" width="100" height="100" fill="#da552f"></rect>
        <text class = "play" x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue">Hello</text>
      </g>
  </svg>  
  <img src="./images/play-video.svg" alt="play-video" />
</div>
```

CSS

Remove other css that you have given to svg component.

```
.video-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Your Demo**
[CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/ksilentstorm/pen/LYEexMw)

Comment: the rectangle does not appear on top of the image, and it does not have any text on top of it

Comment: I have updated an answer, now check. Also visit Codepen, for review.

Comment: hi, still the text with the box do not appear on TOP of the image. they appear vertically above it. I need them to appear as a layer on top of the image. how do I go about it?

Comment: Have you wrapped your both text and and rect inside the <g></g> ??

Comment: with the new code, it places the text in the upper left corner of the video-container. if top = 1, the text box goes below the video container. how can this be resolved?

Comment: I did wrap in <g></g>. it does not change things. the text appears on top of the box. but the box goes below the video container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205502/discussion-between-ksilentstorm-and-user8000626).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <section class = "overpass-info-container">
      <div class="description-container">
        <div class = "what-is">
          What is Overpass
        </div >
        <p class="details">
          Overpass connects phone talent from around the world with
          businesses looking to build remote customer engagement teams to
          increase sales, generate leads and so much more.
       </p>
      </div>

      <div class = "video-container">
          <img class = "video" src="./images/play-video.svg" alt="play-video" />

          <svg width="190" height="63">
            <g>
              <rect x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5" width="190px" height="63px" fill="#0092FF"/>
              <text x="50%" y="50%"  fill="white" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Play Video</text>
            </g>
          </svg>
      </div>
    </section>
```

```
overpass-info-container {
  background-color: #0092FF;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.description-container {
  margin-top: 155px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.what-is {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-weight: 330;
  font-family: Proxima Nova;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
}


.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 142px;
  }

.video-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #00000029;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.overpass-info-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 182px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../images/curve.svg") bottom center;
  background-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```